# plotting several functions: order influences Timing

Tags: plotting, timing

Consider the following, fairly long, function definition (note however that it only consist of the elementary operations addition, multiplication and exponentiation):

```
fun[x_] = 439.2526370226815*
    E^(300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
    ((18.34195787125195*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
       (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
         15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
         E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2*
       (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
      (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 - 
     (18.34195787125195*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
       (75*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        90*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        9*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
       (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
      (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2 - 
     (55.02587361375585*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
       (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
         15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
         E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2)/
      (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
        E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2 + 
     (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
       300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
       180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
       12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))/
      (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
       50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
       20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
       E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))) + 
     0.007210807153437529*
      ((85536*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^5 - 
       (85536*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (75*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          90*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          9*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3)/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 - 
       (256608*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4)/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 - 
       (14580*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2*
         (5 + 50*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          45*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 + 
       (4860*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (150*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          270*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          36*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2)/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 + 
       (9720*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (75*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          90*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          9*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 50*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          45*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 + 
       (43740*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2*
         (5 + 50*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          45*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 + 
       (36*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (10575*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          81420*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          154440*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          101520*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          18225*E^(4200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          972*E^(5100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2 - 
       (72*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (360 + 3525*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          13570*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          17160*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          8460*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1215*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          54*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 + 
       (216*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (360 + 3525*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          13570*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          17160*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          8460*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1215*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          54*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2) + 
     0.0006123163010466359*
      ((40870656*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^6*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^7 - 
       (40870656*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (75*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          90*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          9*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^5)/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^6 - 
       (122611968*E^(5100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^6)/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^6 - 
       (13996800*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4*
         (5 + 50*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          45*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^6 + 
       (2799360*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (150*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          270*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          36*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4)/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^5 + 
       (11197440*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (75*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          90*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          9*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3*
         (5 + 50*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          45*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^5 + 
       (41990400*E^(4200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4*
         (5 + 50*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          45*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^5 - 
       (6*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (172350*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          2046180*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4985820*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          4320900*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          984150*E^(4200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          69984*E^(5100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2 - 
       (324*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2*
         (884700*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          11875020*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          28820340*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20629620*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3855600*E^(4200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          203472*E^(5100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 + 
       (12*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5295 + 57450*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          341030*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          553980*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          360075*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          65610*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3888*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 - 
       (36*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5295 + 57450*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          341030*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          553980*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          360075*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          65610*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3888*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2 + 
       (1296*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5535 + 294900*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*
               x)) + 1979170*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 
              3.3333333333333326*x)) + 3202260*
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1719135*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          257040*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          11304*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^5 - 
       (648*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (75*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          90*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          9*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (5535 + 294900*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*
               x)) + 1979170*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 
              3.3333333333333326*x)) + 3202260*
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1719135*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          257040*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          11304*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 - 
       (3888*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (5 + 25*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           15*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^2*
         (5535 + 294900*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*
               x)) + 1979170*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 
              3.3333333333333326*x)) + 3202260*
           E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1719135*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          257040*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          11304*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 - 
       (1620*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (212625*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3279450*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          17508105*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          38682900*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          39792075*E^(4200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          19115730*E^(5100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3971835*E^(6000*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          359640*E^(6900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          11664*E^(7800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3 + 
       (4860*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (60*E^(600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          300*E^(1500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          180*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          12*E^(3300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))*
         (3600 + 70875*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          546575*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1945345*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3223575*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          2652805*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1061985*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          189135*E^(6300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          14985*E^(7200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          432*E^(8100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^4 - 
       (14580*E^(2400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))*
         (3600 + 70875*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          546575*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1945345*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          3223575*E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          2652805*E^(4500*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          1061985*E^(5400*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          189135*E^(6300*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          14985*E^(7200*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          432*E^(8100*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x))))/
        (1 + 20*E^(900*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          50*E^(1800*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          20*E^(2700*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)) + 
          E^(3600*(-3.3348195385623947 + 3.3333333333333326*x)))^3))
```

Upon plotting this function in combination with a modification of it, I noticed something strange: the order of the functions influences the time the plot takes:

```
Plot[{(-0.000189716182236671 + 1/fun[x])^-1, fun[x]}, {x, 0.997, 1.002}] // RepeatedTiming
```

gives me a timing of 1.960 on my machine, in contrast:

```
Plot[{fun[x], (-0.000189716182236671 + 1/fun[x])^-1}, {x, 0.997, 1.002}] // RepeatedTiming
```

results in a timing of 2.86. I have other examples where this is even more extreme.

At first I suspected the order influences the number of sampling points, after adding the option `Mesh -> All` I don't think so anymore. The only possible explanation I have left is that Mathematica can somehow exploit the fact that the functions are related, however I don't understand why this should only work in the first case...

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that plotting them individually and combining them afterwards with `Show` is ~50% faster that either of your versions...